# Mocking custom promise rejection with jest and react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am attempting to test code within a catch block using React Testing Lib and jest.
Requests are handled within the component via axios.

I am mocking axios as follows:

```
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
```

Using `mockRejectedValue`

```
  test('return throws error', async () => {
    mockedAxios.post.mockRejectedValue({ statusText: 'blah', status: 404 });
    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/username/i), 'blah');
    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/password/i), 'blah');
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));
    const error = await screen.findByText(/404 blah/i);
    expect(error).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Within the catch block:

```
...
} catch (error) {
      console.log(error) //above test logs the error as undefined
      
      let errMessage = 'Service Error'; //fallback error


      if (isErrorResp(error)) { //error with specific properties I want to test
        errMessage = `${error.status} ${error.statusText}`;
      }

      setNetworklError({ error: true, message: errMessage });
      setIsloading(false);

    }
```

The above test appropriatly rejects the promise and hits the catch block.
The logged `error` within jest is always undefined. As such `isErrorResp(error)` never triggers and the ui only displays the fallback error.

I am not sure how to pass a mocked rejection with a custom response.

Comment: What happens with, what I presume is called, `networklError`?

Comment: Since the caught error is undefined, `errMessage` remains 'Service Error'
so `networkError = { error: true, message: 'Service Error' }`.

Ideally `error` would be `{ statusText: 'blah', status: 404 }`

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)